# Assistance on creating dynamic menu pop ups -js

Tags: javascript, html, css

**What I'm trying to do**

Alright so I basically want the div with the class **js-op** to pop up under each of the icons that are clicked on my side [bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkMDS.png). Right now all I have is whenever a user clicks on the icons a popup well pops up.

**What I'm trying to do**

Ok so I ran though all the icons using a for loop, so that its being watched for any clicked actions. Im new to javascript so I think this is a huge accomplishment! Now Im a bit stuck, basically now I just want javascript to add the class *.js-display*  found on the last line (.css) to the class **js-op**, respectfully. Meaning under each icon there is a div that has that class. (It is set to display:none) When that icon is clicked that div right under it will get the *.js-display* so that it becomes visible. I am essentially creating dynamic popup menus.

**Extra**

*Im gonna end up asking later*

Ok so this icon is clicked right? A panel displays, but the user decides to click on another icon. Is it possible to have the first panel that was displayed first, disappear?

**Thank you**

Again thank you!

Now if Im not suppose to have the extra thing in here please tell me, before down voting( I heard stack can be a little harsh) Im not sure, I feel like its still relevant to the main question.

**js**

```
var pop_action = document.getElementById("js-uX-pop_up").getElementsByClassName("uX-nv-spn ");
var pop_panel = document.getElementsByClassName("js-op");

for(e_op = 0; e_op < pop_action.length; e_op++ ){   

    pop_action[e_op].addEventListener("click", activate_eop);

}

function activate_eop(){
alert("hello");
}
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\XSystem.css">

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Xlaeo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- section that holds mains -->
        <div class="xU-wper xU-flex-1-1">
            <!-- section holds two sends -->
            <section class="xU-flex uX-maon-wper">
                <!-- BEGIN LEFT: bar -->
                <section class="uX-maon-sc xU-white">
                    <div class="uX-fluid ">
                        <span class="uX-bar-modules-wper">
                            <!-- modules for side bar  -->
                            <!-- BEGIN Image company -->
                            <div class="uX-company-img">
                                <span>
                                <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-hardware-devices/96/Motherboard-icon.png"/>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end image -->
                            <!-- BEGIN  side bar list-->
                            <div class="uX-list-modules uX-them-pd">
                                <span class="uX-side-nav " id="js-uX-pop_up" role="navigation">
                                    <li >

                                        <span class="uX-nv-spn">
                                            <a>
                                                    <i class="fab fa-d-and-d"></i>
                                            </a>

                                        </span>
                                        <!-- POPUP -->
                                        <div class="js-op"  style="display:none">

                                            <section>
                                                pop up
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li >
                                        <span class="uX-nv-spn">
                                        <i class="fab fa-mandalorian"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <!-- POPUP -->
                                        <div class="js-op" style="display:none">
                                            <section>
                                                pop up2
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="uX-nv-spn">
                                        <i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <!-- POPUP -->
                                        <div class="" style="display:none">
                                            <section>
                                                pop up
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li >
                                        <span class="uX-nv-spn  ">
                                        <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <!-- POPUP -->
                                        <div class="" style="display:none">
                                            <section>
                                                pop up
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="uX-nv-spn">
                                        <i class="fab fa-java"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <!-- POPUP -->
                                        <div class="uX_popU" style="display:none">
                                            <section>
                                                pop up
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end side bar list-->
                            <!-- profile image -->
                            <div class="">
                                <a>
                                    <span class="uX-items-center">
                                        <div class="uX_profile-img-wper">
                                            <img src="https://cdn.imaginetricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Wonderful-Cute-Girls-Profile-Picture.jpg"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>Emma</span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end proifle image   -->
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <!-- END LEFT: bar -->
                <!-- BEGIN RIGHT: bar -->
                <section class="uX-maon-sc uX-maon-sc2">
                    content
                </section>
                <!-- END RIGHT: bar -->
            </section>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Js-script/mod-up.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Css**

```
.xU-flex-1-1, .uX-bar-modules-wper, .uX-fluid, .uX-list-modules, .uX-side-nav li, html,
body, .uX-maon-sc, .uX-items-center, .uX-side-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; }

.xU-flex, .uX-side-nav {
  display: flex; }

.xU-flex-1-1, .uX-bar-modules-wper, .uX-fluid, .uX-list-modules, .uX-side-nav li {
  flex: 1 1 auto; }

.uX-side-nav li {
  justify-content: center; }

.uX_profile-img-wper {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; }

.xU-font, .uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #c62f09; }

.uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn:hover {
  background: lightgray; }

.uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn:hover {
  border-radius: 100%; }

.uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn {
  height: 2.2rem;
  width: 2.2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }

body {
  background: #f4f4f4; }
  body li {
    list-style-type: none; }

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }

.xU-white {
  background: white; }

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.uX-maon-wper, .uX-maon-sc2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto; }

.uX_profile-img-wper {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem; }

.uX-items-center {
  align-items: center; }

.uX-bar-modules-wper .uX-company-img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; }

.uX-bar-modules-wper .uX-list-modules {
  padding: 0.4rem; }

.uX-side-nav {
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto; }
  .uX-side-nav li {
    height: 100%; }
  .uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn {
    padding: 0.4rem;
    border-radius: 100%; }

.uX-list-modules {
  border-right: 1px solid #c62f09; }

.js-display {
  display: block; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=XSystem.css.map */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing 'js-op' classes on all of the elements. Also, inline styles always override class/id styles, therefore you need to change

```
.js-display {display: block;}
```

to

```
.js-display {display: block !important;}
```

or it won't work.

You also didn't provide any JS here, so I had to just make it up, but you get the idea. This should do it:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.uX-side-nav li').forEach((el)=>{
  el.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('.js-op').forEach((x)=>{x.classList.remove('js-display');});
    e.target.closest('li').querySelector('.js-op').classList.add('js-display');
  });                                                    
});
```

```css
.xU-flex-1-1, .uX-bar-modules-wper, .uX-fluid, .uX-list-modules, .uX-side-nav li, html,
body, .uX-maon-sc, .uX-items-center, .uX-side-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; }

.xU-flex, .uX-side-nav {
  display: flex; }

.xU-flex-1-1, .uX-bar-modules-wper, .uX-fluid, .uX-list-modules, .uX-side-nav li {
  flex: 1 1 auto; }

.uX-side-nav li {
  justify-content: center; }

.uX_profile-img-wper {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; }

.xU-font, .uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #c62f09; }

.uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn:hover {
  background: lightgray; }

.uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn:hover {
  border-radius: 100%; }

.uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn {
  height: 2.2rem;
  width: 2.2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }

body {
  background: #f4f4f4; }
  body li {
    list-style-type: none; }

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }

.xU-white {
  background: white; }

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.uX-maon-wper, .uX-maon-sc2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto; }

.uX_profile-img-wper {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem; }

.uX-items-center {
  align-items: center; }

.uX-bar-modules-wper .uX-company-img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; }

.uX-bar-modules-wper .uX-list-modules {
  padding: 0.4rem; }

.uX-side-nav {
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto; }
  .uX-side-nav li {
    height: 100%; }
  .uX-side-nav .uX-nv-spn {
    padding: 0.4rem;
    border-radius: 100%; }

.uX-list-modules {
  border-right: 1px solid #c62f09; }

.js-display {
  display: block !important; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=XSystem.css.map */
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\XSystem.css">

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Xlaeo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- section that holds mains -->
        <div class="xU-wper xU-flex-1-1">
            <!-- section holds two sends -->
            <section class="xU-flex uX-maon-wper">
                <!-- BEGIN LEFT: bar -->
                <section class="uX-maon-sc xU-white">
                    <div class="uX-fluid ">
                        <span class="uX-bar-modules-wper">
                            <!-- modules for side bar  -->
                            <!-- BEGIN Image company -->
                            <div class="uX-company-img">
                                <span>
                                <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-hardware-devices/96/Motherboard-icon.png"/>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end image -->
                            <!-- BEGIN  side bar list-->
                            <div class="uX-list-modules uX-them-pd">
                                <span class="uX-side-nav " id="js-uX-pop_up" role="navigation">
                                    <li>
  <span class="uX-nv-spn">
    <i class="fab fa-d-and-d"></i>
  </span>
  <div class="js-op"  style="display:none">
    <section>
      pop up1
    </section>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="uX-nv-spn">
   
    <i class="fab fa-mandalorian"></i>
  </span>
  <div class="js-op" style="display:none">
    <section>
      pop up2
    </section>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="uX-nv-spn">
    <i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"></i>
  </span>
  <div class="js-op" style="display:none">
    <section>
      pop up3
    </section>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="uX-nv-spn  ">
    <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>
  </span>
  <div class="js-op" style="display:none">
    <section>
      pop up4
    </section>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="uX-nv-spn">
    <i class="fab fa-java"></i>
  </span>
  <div class="js-op" style="display:none">
    <section>
      pop up5
    </section>
  </div>
</li>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end side bar list-->
                            <!-- profile image -->
                            <div class="">
                                <a>
                                    <span class="uX-items-center">
                                        <div class="uX_profile-img-wper">
                                            <img src="https://cdn.imaginetricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Wonderful-Cute-Girls-Profile-Picture.jpg"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>Emma</span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end proifle image   -->
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <!-- END LEFT: bar -->
                <!-- BEGIN RIGHT: bar -->
                <section class="uX-maon-sc uX-maon-sc2">
                    content
                </section>
                <!-- END RIGHT: bar -->
            </section>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Js-script/mod-up.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh im sorry I completely forgot my js. I added it! but I would like to not use jQuery, as must as possible on my professional website for my company.

Comment: yeah i didnt bother using that class in all of the elements cuz i was just testing

Comment: Ok, well that code I gave you works as you expected (assuming you add the classes to the popups) and it's not JQuery, so I'm assuming this is resolved. If you don't want the classes then just replace the ".js-op" in the selector with "div".

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't put it in my code, you would use CSS. If you must, you would add it below:

e.target.closest('li').querySelector('.js-op').classList.add('js-display');

using this as your popup selector:

e.target.closest('li').querySelector('.js-op');

Comment: Thanks again bro! Just 16 and tryna learn js so my companies website can be dynamic etc. Thank you for taking the time to help out. Sorry about the missing js file.